# R: read.table interprets \r as new line

Tags: r, read.table, line-endings

### Summary

I try to read twitter data with `read.table`. But I have lines terminated only in `\r` which causes problems, so I'd like to skip some lines.

### Data format

The data is in a tab-separated csv and of the following form:

```
id \t userid \t date \t latitude \t longitude \t location \t tweet \r\n
```

(Note: I added spaces for readability, and `\t`, `\r` and `\n` are as expected TAB, CR and LF)

Some examples are:

```
488397447040086017  1220042672  20140713190000  -22.923528  -43.238966  Rio de Janeiro, Rio de Janeiro  os moradores da minha rua devem me odiar
488397446960381952  1960969112  20140713190000  60.998575   68.998468   Ханты-Мансийск, Ханты-Мансийск  Вот интересом, мне одной пофиг на футбол?
488397446997762049  1449959828  20140713190000  32.777693   -97.307257  Fort Worth, TX  Buena suerte Argentina
```

### Reading in data

There were some problems (`#` as comments, `'` as quote character, encoding, ...) which I partly solved already:

```
readTweets <- function(fileName) {
  # read tweets from file
  tweets <- read.table(fileName, sep = "\t", quote = "", comment.char = "",
                       col.names = c("id", "user", "date", "latitude", 
                                     "longitude", "location", "tweet"),
                       colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric", "character",
                                      "double", "double", "character",
                                      "character"), encoding = "utf8")

  tweets
}
```

As you can easily see I also added the `colClasses` parameter to give the fields some useful types (I also changed the date column to `POSIXct`, but I have to do the formatting myself - side quest: is there a way to apply functions to imported columns automatically?).

### The error

This worked on a small test set like the one given above. However, when I tried to load a bigger dataset, I got the following error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '(:'
```

A little bit of searching through the file shows the following entry:

```
488397464438071297  403662206   20140713190004  19.320504   -76.426316      @Toneishe_Lovee @purifiedhoran 
(:
```

This looks like there is just a newline in the wrong place! That's a huge problem now, how can I say that a line is a new line or not? And why is it that way? I decided to have a more detailed look and found out (spaces added again, now you see why I posted the format more exactly) using the "Show all characters" Option in Notepad++ how the entry really looks like:

```
488397464438071297 \t 403662206 \t 20140713190004 \t 19.320504 \t -76.426316 \t @Toneishe_Lovee @purifiedhoran \r (: \r\n
```

Note the `CR` in front of the smiley.

### The simple solution

I somehow "solved" this problem by reading in the first column as characters, filling up the rows and setting empty fields to `NA` and then using `complete.cases`:

```
readTweets <- function(fileName) {
  # read tweets from file
  tweets <- read.table(fileName, sep = "\t", quote = "", comment.char = "",
                       col.names = c("id", "user", "date", "latitude", 
                                     "longitude", "location", "tweet"),
                       colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "character",
                                      "double", "double", "character",
                                      "character"), encoding = "utf8",
                       fill = TRUE, na.strings = TRUE)
  # remove incorrect rows and convert id to numeric
  tweets      <- tweets[complete.cases(tweets[,c("id", "user", "date")]),]
  tweets$id   <- as.numeric(tweets$id)
  rownames(tweets) <- NULL
  tweets
}
```

I still wonder if it's even possible to enter CRs in twitter or the person who gave me the csv files just messed the format up.

### The professional solution

Is it possible to skip non-full lines (without processing all the data again) so that I can use the colClass numeric for the ID directly?

### OS/File/etc.

As requested in the comments here some more technical information:

- $platform: "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
- $system: "x86_64, mingw32"
- $svn rev: "66115"
- $version.string: "R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)"
- OS: Windows 8 (I didn't expect R to be running with my mingw installation)

Example file:

- [Download](http://sebastian-hoeffner.de/files/tweets.csv), 788 B, csv (tab separated), contains 5 tweets including the errorneous one (the second)
- File format is UTF-8 without BOM, Notepad++ identifies the line endings as Dos\Windows

Comment: Without a sample file to play with, it's hard to create a sample with the same bytes are yours to do any testing. Also, what OS and R version are you running as line feeds differ by OS.

Comment: Where should I best upload files for stack overflow so that they are available for generations?
I am using Windows, but the file itself shouldn't differ from OS to OS. R is version 3.1.1. I'll add the information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since R runs on multiple OSes, and different OSes use different line endings, it can be quite difficult to control exactly what gets used as a line ending that will work across all OSes. The easiest way to fix this would be to wrap the tweet column in quotes. When you have quoted fields, embedded linefeeds are allowed. Otherwise you can manipulate the bytes with regular expressions and such. It all depends on what you intend to do with the embedded newlines. Not sure if you want to preserve them or not.

Here's a dump of your sample file

```
ctx <- "488397464357974017\t2168124983\t20140713190004\t24.584653\t46.540044\tالرياض, المملكة العربية السعودية\tأتوقع البطولة أرجنتينية ، من بداية البطولة كل الظروف والعوامل تريد الأرجنتين ..\r\n488397464438071297\t403662206\t20140713190004\t19.320504\t-76.426316\t\t@Toneishe_Lovee @purifiedhoran \r(:\r\n488397464442265600\t2510306157\t20140713190004\t36.517741\t-5.317234\tGaucín, Málaga\t#AlemaniaArgentina Vamos #GER\r\n488397464584871936\t539048975\t20140713190004\t42.550627\t9.440454\tLucciana, Haute-Corse\ton a tous le seum contre Pauline 4/5 mais dsl zayn l'a pas unfollow , ça fait 5 mois que vous sortez ça \U0001f615\r\n488397463997276160\t194876164\t20140713190004\t37.724866\t-120.93389\tRiverbank, CA\t@AlexxisAvila Shhh! Lol\r\n"
```

We can split it up into a character matrix with

```
mm <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(ctx, "\r\n")[[1]], "\t"))
```

Then we can convert to a data.frame

```
dd<-data.frame(mm, stringsAsFactors=F)
dd[,c(1,2,4,5)]<-lapply(dd[,c(1,2,4,5)], as.numeric)
```

then if you write this out to a file (and allow the character values to be quoted)

```
write.table(dd, "tweets2.csv", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t")
```

You can read it back in without problems with

```
dd2 <- read.table("tweets2.csv", sep = "\t", comment.char = "",
    col.names = c("id", "user", "date", "latitude", 
        "longitude", "location", "tweet"),
    colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "character",
        "double", "double", "character",
         "character"),
    encoding = "utf8")
```

So if the file came to you with the quotes around the last column, it would be much easier to import it.

And if you want to read the file in as one big character string as I did to create `ctx`, you can do that with

```
ctx <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
```

which may be helpful if you want to do another manipulations first. For example, you might want to remove the `\r` values that not followed by `\n`. You could do what with

```
gsub("\\r(?!\\n)","[nl]", ctx, perl=T)
```

and i think you can read that directly into read.table

```
read.table(text=gsub("\\r(?!\\n)","[nl]", ctx, perl=T), sep="\t")
```

(I'm testing on a Mac which uses different line endings so it doesn't work, but it might on windows).

Comment: I still don't understand how the line endings can differ for the same file: I have lots of files which terminate just in an LF and therefor are not shown correctly in the windows editor. However notepad++ always shows the correct line terminations.

Either way, your `readChar` in combination with `gsub` did the trick quite well (although I changed the regex to `\\r(?!\\n)`, which I think is easier to interpret) and helps me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that the line endings are different in the file, I just think the tweet column had an embedded `\r`. You can have new lines in tweets so that seems completely valid. Yes, that version of the regex is easier to read. I thought I had tried that on my mac but it didn't work; however upon retesting it seems to work just fine. I'll update the answer.